# How can I create a gradle task to generate exploded war with Sprint boot "bootWar" plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, war

I use the "org.springframework.boot" plugin and use the bootWar task to generate a war file of my spring boot project.
I would like to have a task that creates an exploded version of this war file.

The standard way to do that with the 'war' plugin is :

```
task explodedWar(type: Sync) {
    into "${war.archivePath.parentFile.getAbsolutePath()}/exploded/${war.archivePath.name}"
    with war
}
```

How can i do the same thing with the spring-boot/bootWar plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
task explodeBootWar(type: Sync) {
    dependsOn bootWar
    into "$buildDir/boot_war_exploded"
    from project.zipTree(bootWar.archiveFile)
}
```

You can use the `with` method on the normal `war` task because it is basically just a `copySpec`. However, the `bootWar` task does some additional things, so you have to build and unzip the actual archive.